# Fixed effects model without time?

Tags: r, replication, panel-data

I have a problem with replicating a fixed effects estimations with some kind of panel data structure (but no time index).

I've seen several good explanations for FE-models and some easy application in R. But I'm working at some paper which does not include a time-index but three different indices (person, village, block). Whereas block is the FE (some administrative unit).

Here is what the authors do (FE-estimation):

[image]

Here is some of their results:

[image]

**Question**: I would like to replicate, say, column 3, the coefficient and the robust SE.

(Link to the data: https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20150474 )

**My approach so far**:

To get an idea:

```
# making up some data
person_id <- c(1,3,4,5,7,8)
person_id <- as.integer(person_id)  # integer
village_id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2) 
village_id <- as.integer(village_id) # # integer
block <- c("a","a","b","b","c","c") # character
block <- as.factor(block) # factor
treat <- c(0,1,1,0,1,0) # numeric
treat <- as.integer(treat) # integer
outcome <- c(13,7,8,22,91,2) # numeric

# combining data
df <- cbind(person_id, village_id, block, outcome, treat)
df <- as.data.frame(df)

# converting data, not really necessary
pdata <- plm.data(df, index=c("person_id", "village_id"))

# just for comparison
lm(outcome ~ treat, data=df) # no problem
lm(outcome ~ treat + block, data=df) # no problem 

# using panel data structure, error: empty model
FE <- plm(outcome ~ treat, data=pdata, method="within") 
# alternative, , error: empty model
FE <- plm(outcome ~ treat, data=pdata, method="within", index=c("person_id", "village_id"))
```

It's not possible to just create panel data with 3 indices like in `pdata <- plm.data(df, index=c("person_id", "village_id", "block"))` but I can't tell the reason. Still it seems that R interprets those indices as "time".

I managed to set up a pooling-model (this yields the perfect coefficient, don't know why, I would like a within-model):

```
pooling<- plm(DV_dap ~ gotminikit + paddyarea + block, data=r_farmlevel_year2, model="pooling", index=c("farmer_id", "village_id")) # coef 393.768 fits!
```

and adjusted the calculation of robust SE (just trial and error):

```
coeftest(pooling, vcov=pvcovHC(pooling, method="arellano", cluster="time", type="HC0")) # 135.377
coeftest(pooling, vcov=pvcovHC(pooling, method="arellano", cluster="time", type="HC1")) # 135.927
coeftest(pooling, vcov=pvcovHC(pooling, method="arellano", cluster="time", type="HC2")) # 136.705 - pretty close!
coeftest(pooling, vcov=pvcovHC(pooling, method="arellano", cluster="time", type="HC3")) # 138.087
```

I don't have enough econometric background to decide between those ways of SE-calculation. But none of them results in exactly the given number of 136.410.

A linear model (as suggested) get's me very close to the results, but doesn't yield a perfect match:

```
lmodel <- lm(DV_dap ~ r_farmlevel_year2$gotminikit + r_farmlevel_year2$paddyarea + r_farmlevel_year2$block) 
coeftest(lmodel , vcov = sandwich) # coef 393.768  SE  137.775
```

I would appreciate any hints :)

Comment: what is it that you're trying to do? It nots completely clear to me. PLM is for panel models -you don't have panel data -i.e. no repeated measures on the same observations. You can add fixed effects to a basic linear model by rendering the variable you're using for the FE as a factor : ``lm(outcome ~ treat + as.factor(block), data=df)``

Comment: I try to replicate some empirical results. Later on I need to calculate robust standard errors and thought that only possible with coeftest() / vcov with a panel model.

Comment: so if you have ``model<-lm(outcome ~ treat + as.factor(block), data=df)`` then to get the robust standard errors you can use: ``coeftest(model, vcov = sandwich)``

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian this works in principle to calculate "one kind" of robust SE. But I already tried all kind of vcov = vcovHC(HC0/1/2/...), method=arellano. It never exactly fits the numbers from the paper.

Comment: @Mac: The pooling model runs well because you are not considering a panel data structure (actually the data as you explain do not follow a structure like this). The fixed effect, normally, aims to capture some unobservable characteristic associated to the units of analysis (e.g. farmer for your case) that does not change over time (normally gender or things like that). Your data I think presents some sort of hierarchy (farms < villages < blocks) so I would suggest to have a look at fixed-effects in hierarchical data structures.

Comment: I will think about it and reconsider my question :) I was just confused because I did not manage to replicate the central model equation. thx

Comment: @Mac, another alternative  might be to consider a two-way fixed effect model. I cannot replicate your the data but considering the information above it would be something like this: `plm(outcome ~ treat, data=pdata,  index=c("person_id", "village_id"),method="within", effect = "twoways")`